# Copy LocalDate to another place in calendar in java.time

Tags: java, java-time

I want to copy day (from some period of time) from one place in calendar to another. But there are few restriction. I will show it by some example.

Let's say that I want to copy 5th of June (it is Wednesday, variable dayToCopy). This week starts at 3rd of June(variable sourceWeekStart). The target week date is a 10th of December(Monday, variable targetWeekStart). As we see, because source day is Wednesday the targetDay should be here at 12th of December.

It was the easy part (could use TemporalAdjuster here). 
But the problem is when I want to copy let's say 12th of June(source week is still 3rd of June). Now the targetDay should be 19th of December. I don't know how to do that cause TemporalAdjuster match it to next week only. Can anyone help me with this?

```
LocalDate convertTemplateTimeToRealTime(LocalDate dayToCopy, LocalDate sourceWeekStart, LocalDate targetWeekStart) {

        long daysBetweenSourceWeekStartAndDayToCopy = DAYS.between(sourceWeekStart, dayToCopy.toLocalDate());

//HERE SHOULD BE THE SOLUTION
    }
```

Comment: Since the logic doesn't seem obvious I reccomend to provide appriopriate unit tests before implementing the solution - you'll be sure it works properly :)

Answer (score 3):

Set target day to `targetWeekStart.plusDays(daysBetweenSourceWeekStartAndDayToCopy)` if I didn’t misunderstand.

**Link:** [Documentation of `LocalDate.plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays(long))